# Use form reset on Chosen Multiple Select

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using a multiple chosen select (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple) in a project and I can get it working fine posting through the data I select but how do I reset the Multiple select?

In the normal single select the line `$('#id').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');` is enought to fix the problem but the HTML created for the multi chosen is completely different

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of..

```
$('#containerDiv').find('.search-choice').remove();
```

The "containerDiv" would then have to be wrapped around the "multiple choice select" (assuming that the hidden divs are actually placed within this), like:

```
<div id="containerDiv">
<multipleSelectThingie>
</div>
```

Feels a bit like a hack though :-)

Comment: No, i've tried those and it appears to remove them (looking in FireBug) but they repopulate and get processed